# Grouping Outlook threads which adds RE every time external parties respond to mails creating multiple threads of single conversation

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

We engage with external vendors on daily basis. However they use some kind of ticketing tool to respond to our mails. Every time they respond to our mails, it adds extra `RE` to the subject, which ends up creating a separate thread. So for a single case/conversation, we end up getting multiple threads which gets hard to track. Is there any solution in outlook which can group all conversations by removing all `RE`'s from subject and show it together. Is there any good plugin/Add-in which we can use for this particular case?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the feature you're looking for, is not a part of the product.
We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues).
Please add your request here with the label “`Type: product feature request`”.
Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.